# Finding the bounds for a triple integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm currently working on a problem stating:

$\iiint_Q y*dV$, where Q is the solid that lies between the cylinders $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$, above the xy-plane, and below the plane z=x+2.

My thought process was:

since it is above the xy-axis, z must be greater than 0, and less than x+2 (bounded below this)

since $x^2+y^2$ is equivalent to $r^2$, r must be between 1 and 2 (according to our cylinder equations)

Since we are dealing with cylinders, $\theta$ must be between 0 and 2$\pi$.

I did the triple integration using these numbers, which came out to be 0. This can't be right, so I'm just wondering if it was a mistake in my bounds (since I'm very new to this topic), or was it a computation error with my triple integration calculation?

(I'd also like to add that the reason it came out to be 0 is the 0 and 2$\pi$ cancelling everything out in my last integration)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{1}^2 (r\cos \theta+2)rdrd\theta$. I am sure the answer won't be $0$ as claimed.I answered the wrong question, but if you are to find the volume, then this should be fine. For the right set up of the question, $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{1}^2 r\sin \theta(r\cos \theta + 2)rdrd\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to put all proper quantities in terms of polar coordinates.  Observe that $dV = rdrd\theta dz$ in this case, and also that $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$.  Therefore your integration should start with the $z$-variable and should be

$$
\int_1^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{r\cos\theta + 2} r\sin \theta (rdzd\theta dr) \;\; =\;\; \int_1^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{r\cos\theta + 2} r^2\sin\theta dzd\theta dr.
$$

This reduces down to

$$
\int_1^2 \int_0^{2\pi} (r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta + 2r^2\sin\theta)d\theta dr.
$$

The contribution from the first term is zero since $\left .\frac{1}{2} \sin^2\theta \right |_0^{2\pi} = 0$, as well as from the second term since $-\cos\theta |_0^{2\pi} = 0$ as well.  If you want a qualitative explanation for why this is zero, then think about this: when you integrate $\iiint_Q ydV$ you are computing the $y$-centroid of this solid object, which is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.  It therefore makes sense that the $y$-centroid would be zero.